# Load testing in Play! framework

Tags: playframework, load-testing, performance-testing

How do you perform load testing in a Play! project?

Do you use external tools ? if so, which one is best integrated with Play?

Or does Play! have provided some feature about it?

(I'm using Eclipse IDE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for load testing.

From their website:

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and dynamic resources (files, Servlets, Perl scripts, Java Objects, Data Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more). It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, network or object to test its strength or to analyze overall performance under different load types. You can use it to make a graphical analysis of performance or to test your server/script/object behavior under heavy concurrent load.

I've used it at work before for load testing and it works great.